# Which F statistic is generated in felm (R) and why does it differ from STATA (ivreghdfe)

Tags: r, stata, 2sls, f-statistic

I'm running 2sls and making sure that my results replicate in both stata and r. In r, using felm, my code is:

```
a1 <- felm(y ~ 0|year + id | (x ~ z1 +  z2 + z3)|cluster, data = db)
    summary(a1$stage1)
```

In STATA, using ivreghdfe, my code is:
 `ivreghdfe y  (x = z1   z2 z3), absorb(id year) cluster(cluster) first`

The coefficients and standard errors generated by the code look the same in both approaches, but the two commands give me different F statistics, even while assuming the same degrees of freedom. ivreghdfe provides much more detail on which F statistics are being calculated and provides a number of ways to test instrument strength, but none of them correspond to the F statistic reported by R (neither the "projected model" or "full model"). My question is twofold: **What test does the FELM F Statistic correspond to, and why does it differ from the statistics reported by STATA?**

Comment: You might add the `cmethod = 'reghdfe'` option to the `felm`.

Comment: Also, make sure that you have the latest version of both commands.